# Open Xcode debugger only in assistant editor

Tags: xcode, xcode7

Is there any way to force the Xcode debugger to open itself in the assistant editor instead of the main one?  I know you can open it in a separate tab, but I would prefer that it simply open on the right hand side.

Comment: I normally use `option` key to open a file in different editor. Or you can use `option+cmd`+`,` to open the current file in the right hand side.

Comment: Thanks J. Wang. However, my question is really about when the debugger hits a breakpoint.  I don't want it to take over my main window, I want it to take over the assistant window.

Comment: @arsenius If it's possible, it would be part of Xcode's behaviors. Choose Xcode > Behaviors > Edit Behaviors. Select the Pauses step on the left side under Running to see what Xcode can do when it reaches a breakpoint.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk I found an option in behaviors for "`Show` editor as `Assistant Editor`" but it seems to have no effect.  Thanks though.

Comment: has there been an answer to this?